# Open data cube GeoTIFF indexing from MinIO/S3

Tags: open-data-cube

I have large amounts of existing GeoTIFF data and I would need to find example how to index those to open data cube. Currently those reside in MinIO (S3 compliant store). In my understanding I would need to convert these to COG (that I can probably manage) and then I would need to generate STAC file to ingest those.

Any pointer to tutorial or examples?

---

I think s3-to-dc won't work with Minio as there is no way to pass endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

There is a really basic example here in the [Datacube STAC example](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-stac-example) repository.

In brief, if you create a STAC 1.0.0-beta.2 document that uses the Proj extension and includes `transform` and `shape` for each asset, as defined [here](https://github.com/stac-extensions/projection), and a field in properties that is `odc:product`, which relates to your product definition, you should be good to go.

Then you can use the `s3-to-dc` tool, [available here](https://github.com/opendatacube/odc-tools/tree/develop/apps/dc_tools), to index from MinIO.